# how to maven script to gradle?

Tags: spring-boot, maven, gradle, jib

I've been researching the script for a day, but gradle doesn't have enough documentation to find an answer. Any help would be appreciated.

this is pom.xml

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>build-docker-image</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jib-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
    <artifactId>jib-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.4</version>
    <configuration>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>build</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Assuming that you have read the [documentation for Jib’s Gradle plugin](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/tree/master/jib-gradle-plugin), what, specifically, would you like some help with?

Comment: yeah. I've read it a few times already. but i dont understand <executions>, < execution>, <phase>, <goal>, <profiles>, <profiles> .... etc

Comment: That’s Maven configuration that will invoke the Jib’s plugin’s `build` goal when Maven is packaging the application. It’s equivalent to adding Jib’s Gradle plugin and running the `jib` task. Perhaps you can describe what end result you want in general terms and then someone can tell you how to configure Gradle to achieve that result?